# Analysis of insert operation of an array-based list (cursor implementation)

Tags: arraylist, big-o

So I'm studying for my algorithm analysis exam tomorrow and I'm reading over the instructors notes and examples. There's just one thing that I don't understand and it's this question:

> Question: Inserting an element after a given element in an array-based list (cursor implementation) requires worst case time:
>
> Answer: O(1)

Personally, I see the worst case being where the cursor is at the beginning of the list, therefore N-1 items in the array must be copied over to the next position before the new element is inserted and therefore it is an O(N) operation in the worst case.

However, when asked if this was a typo, the instructor stated that it wasn't.

What's the reasoning behind this? To all future answerers, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we have to insert element 'a'. Well it says **given** an element, let's call it 'b'. What that means is you know what the next element is, let's call it 'c'. So all you have to do is to set the 'next' element of 'a' equal to 'c'. Then set the next element of 'b' equal to 'a'. This procedure is valid for any element. So the operation is constant time.

Comment: So it's essentially a linked list. I guess I was thinking that this wasn't legal in an array implementation of a list. I guess there's little difference between this and a singly linked list.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement what is essentially a linked list using an array where each element in the array contains a pointer to the index of the next element.

```
struct Element
{
    string item;
    int next;
}
```

Given element A, you can insert a new element B after A in constant time.

```
int indexOfA = ..
int indexOfB = (next free index)
B.next = A.next;
A.next = indexOfB;
```